# How do I specify a state parameter on a state in the middle of the route (ancestor of target state)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, deep-linking, url-parameters

Spent hours googling and combing through the docs [angular ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) to no avail...seems like this should be really basic.

**The quick version**

---

Looking for something that I imagine might look something like this

```
<a ui-sref="parent({param: value}).child">go</a>
```

or this

```
$state.go("parent.child", {parent:{param: value}})
```

- the idea being that `param` gets applied to `parent`, not `child`, resulting in a url such as `/parent/value/child`

**The long version**

---

**THE SETUP:**

Let's say I have a state that takes a parameter, projectId, like so:

```
.state('manage.project', {
    url: '/project/:projectId',
    templateUrl: 'fragments/projectTemplate.html',
    controller: 'projectController' 
}
```

...then way down the state tree, I have one of many child states that depend on on that parameter:

```
.state('descendantOfProjectState.grandchildState', {
    url: '/projectInfo',
    templateUrl: 'fragments/projectInfo.html',
    controller: function($state){
         var projectId = $state.params.projectId;
    } 
}
```

Normally, one would first visit the parent:

```
$state.go('manage.project', {projectId: 123})
```

At this point the URL would look something like

> /manage/project/123/foo/bar/projectInfo

From there, navigating to a child state is as simple as

```
$state.go("manage.project.foo.bar.descendantOfProjectState.grandchildState");
```

and the projectId is accessible via $state.params by virtue of being in the URL - no need to configure every single child state to explicitly expect the projectId (wondering if this is my fatal flaw).

**THE PROBLEM:**

Now the need has arisen to jump to that grandchild state, *without first visiting the parent state*. That is, I want to go directly to

> /manage/project/123/foo/bar/projectInfo

from **within** the app (so, I want to go to the state, not the url).

How can I specify the projectId parameter for the project state, when it's in the middle of the route I'm navigating to?

```
$state.go('manage.project.foo.bar.descendant.grandchild', {projectId: 123})
```

doesn't inform the the ancestor state that needs the id.

**How can I, in one fell swoop, tell ui-router to go directly to that grandchild state while passing the projectId to manage.project state which is in the middle of the route?**

Comment: You may want to look into interceptors. I recently had an issue where I wanted to check a cookie before any http request (route change or API call) and an $httpProviders.interceptor worked like a charm.

Comment: @ChristianHill, thanks for the reply...but I'm just talking about routing between states using ui-router, which is strictly a client-side operation...no http calls are involved.

Comment: routing is considered an http request. From the documentation: When the application bootstraps, Angular creates an injector that will be used to find and inject all of the services that are required by your app. The injector itself doesn't know anything about what $http or $route services do. In fact, the injector doesn't even know about the existence of these services unless it is configured with proper module definitions.